# Does there exist a unique cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $n$?.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Consider the quotient group $G=(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,+)$. Let $n\in \Bbb N$.

> Then does there exist a unique cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $n$?.

**My try**:

For $n$ consider $m$ such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Then the group $\left\langle \dfrac{m}{n}+\Bbb Z\right\rangle $ is a cylic group of order $n$.

For example if I take $n=4$ then I choose $m=3$ then $\left\{\dfrac{3}{4}+\Bbb Z,\dfrac{6}{4}+\Bbb Z,\dfrac{9}{4}+\Bbb Z,\dfrac{12}{4}+\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z\right\}$ is a cyclic group of order $4$.

Now it's not unique because $\left\{\dfrac{1}{4}+\Bbb Z,\dfrac{2}{4}+\Bbb Z,\dfrac{3}{4}+\Bbb Z,\dfrac{4}{4}+\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z\right\}$ is another  cyclic group of order $4$.

So the answer is there exists a cyclic group of order $n$ but not unique. Am I right?

Please check my answer.

Comment: Hint: Assume $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime and $n$ is positive.  What is the order of $\frac{m}{n}$?

Comment: The group is isomorphic to the group of complex roots of unity, which contains a unique cyclic subgroup of each finite order.

Answer (score 1):

These are *not*, in fact, two different subgroups - e.g. ${6\over 4}+\mathbb{Z}={2\over 4}+\mathbb{Z}$ (do you see why?).

Think about what the generators for a subgroup of order $n$ could be - do you see when they will wind up generating the same subgroups? For example, ${1\over 4}$ and ${3\over 4}$ (or rather, the equivalence classes of these) are distinct elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ with order $4$; are there any others? And ${1\over 4}$ and ${3\over 4}$ happen to generate the same subgroup; will this happen in general?

Comment: Because $\frac{2}{4}+1=\frac{6}{4}$ and $1+\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z$;Is it?

Comment: @BenStokes Yes. In general, $x+\mathbb{Z}$ is exactly the set $\{x+k: k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, so if $x$ and $y$ differ by an integer (like ${2\over 4}$ and ${6\over 4}$) then $x+\mathbb{Z}=y+\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How can I prove it in general?I can see this for a particular example

Comment: Well, let's start small: what are the elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ of order $n$? Once we get a classification of those, then we'll be able to go forward.

Comment: Any element of the form $m/n+\Bbb Z$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$

Comment: @BenStokes Yes, that's right. Now: if $\gcd(m, n)=1$, what do you know about the element $m$ (or rather, $m+n\mathbb{Z}$) in the **ring** $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?